# Replace punctuation with whitespace

Tags: c, optimization

This is my current code:

```
// Yes, the missing single quotation mark is intentional
static void replace_punctuation(char *s, size_t len)
{
    static const unsigned char punctuation[] = ".,;:!?\"()[]{}-";
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (memchr(punctuation, s[i], sizeof punctuation - 1)) {
            s[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

After profiling (cachegrind/Kcachegrind) the program (compiled with optimizations enabled, -O2), this was found to be one bottleneck.
`s` is not a nul-terminated string, so `strpbrk()` can not be used.

How can it be optimized?

Comment: Try a long `switch/case` instead of `memchr`. This will spare the overhead of the function call and traversing the `punctuation` string each time. Will replace it with the jump table though, so needs to be profiled too.

Comment: Did you consider loop onrolling? When you process 8 characters at a time. It can lead to better performance on modern processors by increasing instruction-level parallelism. Might only be beneficial with big inputs.

Comment: Alternatively you can replace any *non-alphanumeric* character with space (if it aligns with your requirement). Use `isalnum` for that. It might help. Or not.

Comment: @ThomasGuntenaar Would you like to provide an example?

Comment: @EugeneSh. That sounds good, I'd give it a try.

Comment: Instead of `memchr` you can use a character map implemented as an array of 256 bools.

Comment: Replace the code with `for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) s[i] = table[(unsigned char) s[i]];` using a suitably initialized `table`. Or `table[s[i]]` where `table` is a properly prepared pointer, accounting for `CHAR_MIN`.

Comment: As @EugeneSh. mentioned you can save time tyring to avoid traversing the `punctuation` string. You could use a lookuptable instead.

Comment: If this works, but you want to improve it, have you considered asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Chris I actually intend to, but thought stackoverflow would be a better place for this.

Comment: Re “`s` is not a nul-terminated string, so `strpbrk`() can not be used”: You could save the last character, replace it with a null character, use `strpbrk`, and restore the last character and handle it manually.

Comment: @Chris And only a select amount of people are interested in C at Codereview. :)

Comment: @Harith There's really no way for `strpbrk` to beat a table look-up version. Because `strpbrk` cannot make assumptions of what's passed to it, nor can it make preparations at compile-time. Additionally, it has to check for the null terminator of both strings.

Comment: @Lundin That's correct. I was trying to say that both beats `memchr()` by a good margin. I'd remove my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a lookup table to directly replace each character:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static void replace_punctuation(char *s, size_t len)
{
    _Static_assert(UCHAR_MAX == 255, "This code is written for eight-bit char.");

    static const char table[UCHAR_MAX + 1] =
        {
            //  First, we initialize table[i] with i.
              0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,  
              8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,   
             16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,   
             24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,   
             32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,   
             40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,   
             48,  49,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,   
             56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,   
             64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,   
             72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,   
             80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,   
             88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,   
             96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103,   
            104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111,  
            112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119,  
            120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127,  
            128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135,  
            136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143,  
            144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151,  
            152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159,  
            160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167,  
            168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175,  
            176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183,  
            184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191,  
            192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199,  
            200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207,  
            208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215,  
            216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223,  
            224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231,  
            232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239,  
            240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247,  
            248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255,  

            /*  Then we replace each punctuation character with a space.
                Overriding previous initializers is specified by C 2018 6.7.9
                19.
            */
            ['.'] = ' ',
            [','] = ' ',
            [';'] = ' ',
            [':'] = ' ',
            ['!'] = ' ',
            ['?'] = ' ',
            ['"'] = ' ',
            ['('] = ' ',
            [')'] = ' ',
            ['['] = ' ',
            [']'] = ' ',
            ['{'] = ' ',
            ['}'] = ' ',
            ['-'] = ' ',
        };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        s[i] = table[(unsigned char) s[i]];
}


#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    char p[] = "This, is- text: with? some [puncutation]!";
    puts(p);
    replace_punctuation(p, strlen(p));
    puts(p);
}
```

To deal with possible implementation-defined behavior in conversion the initializers to a signed `char`, the elements from 128 up can be initialized with `i - 2*(UCHAR_MAX-CHAR_MAX)` instead of just `i`.

Comment: Really wonderful answer. The C standard quote is the final touch.

Comment: Note: Initializing a _signed_ `char` with 128, 129, ... 255 is rarely a problem, yet relies on the very common IDB behavior.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yes, that is a nuisance. The elements from 128 up could be initialized with `i - 2*UCHAR_MAX-CHAR_MAX`.

Comment: ... assuming 2's ubiquitous complement when _signed_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: No, it is universal. Consider some `char` `c`, with signed `char`. If it is nonnegative, it is in [0, `CHAR_MAX`), and `table[(unsigned char) c]` is initialized with `c`. If it is negative, converting it to `(unsigned char)` wraps by C standard specification, so `table[(unsigned char) c]` is `table[c + UCHAR_MAX+1]`, and that is also initialized with `c`. For example, if `c` is −3, `table[(unsigned char) c]` is `table[253]`, and that is initialized with `253 - 2*(UCHAR_MAX-CHAR_MAX)`, which is `253 - 2*(255-127)` = `253 - 256` = `-3`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: If `char` is unsigned, `UCHAR_MAX-CHAR_MAX` is `255-255`, and the initializations all become `table[i] = i`. And whether `char` is two’s complement, one’s complement, or sign-and-magnitude never comes into play.

Comment: Perhaps not universal.  The trouble with soon to be irrelevant non-2's complement encoding is that a _signed_ `char` (if such a beast existed) may have -0 and +0 and this answer maps both of them to the same bits with `table[(unsigned char) s[i]]`.  Using `table[((unsigned char *) s)[i]]` creates unique access as suggested by `<string.h>`  "each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).".  Yet by doing that, the initialization for `table[128...255]` needs to somehow make a -0.

Comment: I'd suggest [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77963761/2410359) survives that quirky case.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a translation map.

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static bool replace_punctuation_map_init_needed = true;
static const char replace_punctuation_map[ UCHAR_MAX+1 ];
static const char *replace_punctuation_punc = ".,;:!?\"()[]{}-";

static void replace_punctuation( char *s, size_t len ) {
   if ( replace_punctuation_map_init_needed ) {
      replace_punctuation_map_init_needed = false;

      for ( size_t i = UCHAR_MAX+1; i--; ) {
         replace_punctuation_map[ i ] = (char)i;
      }

      for ( const char *p = replace_punctuation_punc; *p; ++p ) {
         replace_punctuation_map[ (unsigned char)*p ] = ' ';
      }      
   }

   for ( size_t i = len; i--; ) {
      s[ i ] = replace_punctuation_map[ (unsigned char)s[ i ] ];
   }
}
```

- Works with signed `char`.
- Works with `char` of unusual size (as long as it's smaller than `size_t`).
- Removes the conditional.
- Performs the initialization only once.

Answer (score 3):

Like [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77963354/2410359) good answer with some changes.

- Compile time initialization.
- Use smallest array type as `bool` may be wider than `unsigned char`.
- Re-order parameters for better code analysis.
- Do not assume `unsigned char` size.

```
#include <limits.h>

static void replace_punctuation_alt(size_t len, char s[len]) {
  // ".,;:!?\"()[]{}-"
  static unsigned char table[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { 
      ['.'] = 1, [','] = 1, [';'] = 1, [':'] = 1, ['!'] = 1, ['?'] = 1, ['\"'] = 1, 
      ['('] = 1, [')'] = 1, ['['] = 1, [']'] = 1, ['{'] = 1, ['}'] = 1, ['-' ] = 1};

  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (table[((unsigned char*) s)[i]]) {
      s[i] = ' ';
    }
  }
}
```

or perhaps

```
static void replace_punctuation_alt2(size_t len, char s[len]) {
  // ".,;:!?\"()[]{}-"
  static char table[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { 
      ['.'] = '.' ^ ' ', [','] = ',' ^ ' ', [';'] = ';' ^ ' ',
      [':'] = ':' ^ ' ', ['!'] = '!' ^ ' ', ['?'] = '?' ^ ' ',
      ['"'] = '"' ^ ' ', ['('] = '(' ^ ' ', [')'] = ')' ^ ' ',
      ['['] = '[' ^ ' ', [']'] = ']' ^ ' ', ['{'] = '{' ^ ' ',
      ['}'] = '}' ^ ' ', ['-'] = '-' ^ ' '};

  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    s[i] ^= table[((unsigned char*) s)[i]];
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the second have any advantage over the first?

Comment: @Harith Typically code without branches run a little faster than ones with branches (`if`s).         Yet that is only a tendency.

Comment: It did prove faster than the first one.  :)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oops. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, this becomes O(n) if you use a lookup table.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

static void replace_punctuation(char *s, size_t len)
{
    static bool table[256] = {0};
    static const char *punct = ".,;:!?\"()[]{}-";

    for (const char *ch = punct; *ch; ch++) {
        table[(unsigned char)*ch] = 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (table[(unsigned char)s[i]]) {
            s[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

To further optimize, prepare the table at compile, rather than runtime.

Comment: I guess the table preparation should be moved to a separate function. Or even done offline. FWIW, the OP algorithm is O(n) as well. It is just `O(kn)` with `k` constant (number of possible punctuation characters).